# Is it possible to select users with admin role or moderator in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I need to select all users with admin or moderator role. But when I try this code `$user = Role::with('users')->where('name', '=', 'admin')->orWhere('name', '=', 'moderator')->get();` it's order them by roles like this:

```
    Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 1
                [name] => admin
                [users] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => 1
                                [name] => admin
                                [pivot] => Array
                                    (
                                        [role_id] => 1
                                        [user_id] => 1
                                    )

                            )

                    )

            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [id] => 2
                [name] => moderator
                [users] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => 2
                                [name] => Moderator
                                [pivot] => Array
                                    (
                                        [role_id] => 2
                                        [user_id] => 2
                                    )

                            )
                    )

            )

    )
```

Is there any way to get all users in one array with role admin or moderator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah.  Since you are looking for users based on their role, start from the user instead.

```
$users = User::with('roles')->whereHas('roles', function($q)
{
    $q->whereIn('name', ['admin', 'moderator']);
})->get();
```